AWS IAM Policy Issue: Access to unintended S3 folders despite specific resource definition
I'm encountering an unexpected behavior with AWS IAM policies related to S3 bucket access controls. Here's the scenario:
I've defined the following IAM policy to restrict access to a specific folder in my S3 bucket (Data-mocks):
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Data-mocks/data.io/*"
        }
    ]
}


Despite this policy, I've observed that users or roles associated with this policy can still access folders like Data-mocks/companyid. My understanding is that by specifying "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Data-mocks/data.io/*", access should only be granted to objects under Data-mocks/data.io.
Here's the trust policy associated with the role assuming this policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::arn:user/data.io"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Despite my configuration, users assuming this role seem to gain broader access than intended. Could someone explain why this might be happening?
Is there something I'm missing in how IAM policies evaluate permissions, especially concerning wildcard resources in S3 bucket policies?

Something is off here. You mentioned "users (plural) assuming this role" but the trust policy indicates a single IAM user ARN. Also, ARNs cannot have 'arn' in the account portion afaik. Did you do that to redact the account number?

Hey @jarmod yes I replaced the account number with arn and by multiple users I mean the STS token created helps me put or get data in Other folders of the Data-mocks bucket.

Is your first policy the only policy attached to that user/role?

Yes its the only policy attached to the role , and the role only trusts one user to assume it or use tag session.
And User only just one policy, SES.

The policy shown with resource arn:aws:s3:::Data-mocks/data.io/* will not allow any IAM principal access to arn:aws:s3:::Data-mocks/companyid so I think you're missing something here, specifically another policy that is granting that permission or a superset of it.

that's the issue it is providing the access, I saw one aws doc reference at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex4, when I use something like this the access is restricted.
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Action":"s3:*",
         "NotResource":"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1/uploads/anycompany/*"
      }

I checked nothing else grants it the access. I even created a new user for this sake,that user is able to perform the same action. Even create a new policy, still able to do so.

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. This means that no user can access that bucket unless you have put permissions on the IAM User, or on an IAM Group that the user belongs to, or you have created a Bucket Policy that grants access to the bucket. You will need to identify which policy is granting them access to /companyid and modify it to remove such access. It is generally a good idea to avoid using DENY policies because they can be difficult to control. It is better to limit the permissions given in ALLOW policies.

@JohnRotenstein that’s the fun part I literally created a new user, a new role and yet able to access the sub folder “companyId” of the S3 bucket.  They’re not part of any groups they’re just a user and a role without anything, just a trust policy in Role. And the bucket too doesn’t have any policy or part of any group

In times like this, I go back to First Principles. For example, you could create a new bucket and see whether the IAM User has access to it. Then, test whether the IAM Role has access to this new bucket -- they should be denied access. Then, add a policy to the IAM User and see whether this grants access. At some point you will be able to identify what is different between the new bucket and the existing bucket, which will explain your conundrum.
